# Determine what values of a parameter make consistent a given system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given the system of equations:
>   \begin{align*}
> x+2ay &= a^2 \\
> ax + ay &= a^3+1
> \end{align*}
>   where $a$ is a constant, determine what values of a make this system of equations consistent. Then, solve the system for one of those values of $a$.

So I was thinking of putting this into a matrix but I'm a little confused with the variables $a$ and $x$ and $y$. Would I put the a variable into the matrix or no?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's convenient to put the system in matrix form, in part because of the following:

**Hint** An $n \times n$ linear system $A {\bf x} = {\bf b}$ admits a (unique) solution if $\det A \neq 0$.

Comment: would this be the matrix?
\begin{matrix}
        1 & 2a & a^2 \\
        a & a & a^3 +1 \\
        \end{matrix}

Comment: That's the augmented matrix, yes. In this case, we can write the system as $$\pmatrix{1&2a\\a&a}\pmatrix{x\\y} = \pmatrix{a^2\\a^3 + 1} .$$

Comment: and then i just about row reduction like normal by trying to make the a in the second row a 0? Is this correct?

\begin{matrix}
        1 & 2a & a^2 \\
        0 & -2a^2+a & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}

Comment: Yes, that's one option.

Comment: what would be the next row operation? I'm a little stuck..

Comment: That depends on whether $-2a^2 + a$ is $0$. I wouldn't attempt to row-reduce completely, though. Already, if the $(2, 2)$ entry is not zero, we can solve for $y$ and substitute to get $x$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35074/discussion-between-lil-and-travis).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

A system is consistent if it has at least one solution.

We know that if the determinant of the coefficient matrix is $\ne 0$ one solution exists, so find when the determinant is null  and you find two values for $a$. 
Test these values in the '' know'' vector $(a^2,a^3+1)^T$. If the vector is null than you have infinitely many solutions. If the vector is not null the the system is inconsistent.

Comment: would this be the matrix?
\begin{matrix}
        1 & 2a & a^2 \\
        a & a & a^3 +1 \\
        \end{matrix}

Comment: yes.  Solve $\det \begin{bmatrix}1&2a\\a&a \end{bmatrix}=0$ and substitute the values of $a$ in $(a^2,a^3+1)$. Since the result is not the zero vector,  for these values the system is inconsistent.